# How to check whether one CGPoint is in a Shape?

Tags: swiftui

Let's say I have a `Shape`:

```
struct ShapeA: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 210), control: CGPoint(x: 130, y: 200))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 180, y: 240), control: CGPoint(x: 140, y: 240))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 250), control: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 250))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}
```

and a single CGPoint: `CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)`. How can I check whether this CGPoint is in the `ShapeA` (or any other Shape)

Comment: Your title asks about a Shape containing another Shape, but your text asks about a Shape containing a CGPoint. Please edit one or the other to match.

Answer (score 2):

[`path.contains(point)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/contains(_:eofill:))

(Create `path` by calling `.path(in rect:)` on a ShapeA instance.)

For self-intersecting paths, you should look at the `eoFill` option for dealing with even-odd fill rules.

Comment: for controlling if a CGPoint is in that shape or not, would not be easy just controlling the x and y of that CGPoint?